# readLines function not recognizing separating character "\t"

Tags: r

My input file contains many lines of tab-delineated information in a text file. Below would be a line from the text file:

> 100026    TGACTGCATGACGTACAC  NM_006342.1 TACC3

My code is as follows:

```html
constant_source <- 'constants.R'
source(constant_source)
source(classes_file)

processFile = function(filepath) {
  con = file(filepath, "r")
    
  while ( TRUE ) {
    line = readLines(con, sep="\t")
    print(line)
    
    
    if (length(line) == 0 ) {
      break
    }
  }
  
  close(con)
}
```

The output, however, is as follows:

> 100026\tTGACTGCATGACGTACAC\tNM_006342.1\tTACC3

Why is the readLines function not respecting the separation parameter? I have been toying with this for a while and am stuck. Sorry about this; I just started learning R today. If it makes a difference, I am using RStudio.

Comment: `readLines` doesn't have a 'sep' argument. Why? Cuz it reads ..., well ...   lines. Seems to me you should have gotten an error since R would ordinarily see "sep" as an unrecognized argument. You might want to use `read.delim` , since ISTR that it's default sep argument is "\t"

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `Error in readLines(con, sep = "\t") : unused argument (sep = "\t")`. How can you get the posted output?